# knockout - wait for multiselect data to populate before selecting values

Tags: knockout.js

I've got a kendoMultiSelect widget in my page that gets it's values from a JSON call and gets the selected values from a separate JSON call.

```
<select id="locations" data-bind="kendoMultiSelect: {data: locations_list, value: spm.locations}" class="form-control"></select>

function SchedulerProfileModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.locations = ko.observableArray();
}

function SchedulerProfile(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.locations_list = ko.observableArray(['--------']);
}

function MakeAjaxCalls(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/location',
      data: {"q": JSON.stringify(filters)},
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(data) { 
        for (var i = data.objects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            self.locations_list.push(data.objects[i].name+": "+data.objects[i].state_province);
        };
      }
    });
}

function CurrentSchedulerProfile() {
    //does the current user already have a shceduler profile?  
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/schedulerprofile',
      data: "q=" + JSON.stringify({"single":true,"filters":[{"name": "user_id", "op": "eq", "val": self.user_id()}]}),
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(data) { 
        self.requesttype = "put";

        for (var i = data.locations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            self.spm.locations.push(data.locations[i].name+": "+data.locations[i].state_province);
        };
    });
}

$.when(MakeAjaxCalls()).then(CurrentSchedulerProfile);
```

This works fine in dev - it all times up nicely.  The problem is that when I deploy to production the locations_list observable doesn't seem to populate before the spm.locations observable.  The locations_list is pretty big.  In other words, I get no selected values in the multiselect.  The values of the observables are correct on the page - I can output the text of spm.locations and it's right.  I've tried playing around with the ratelimit but that doesn't seem to work either.  I've even tried making the two ajax calls synchronous and that doesn't help.  I feel like the secret sauce is in the ratelimit but what's the way to make one observable wait on a different observable to populate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe on your observable array change

```
 self.spm.locations.subscribe(function (newValue) {
   if (newValue && newValue.length > 0) {
      // newValue is set, we can populate our locations_list now
   }
}, this)
```

BTW you don't want push values to the `observableArray` one by one, push it into temp array, see this [post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html)

Comment: Not familiar with subscribe - in reading the documentation, wouldn't I rather need to subscribe to locations_list?  I want to wait for all the locations to finish loading from the server before selecting the ones in the multiselect?  Am I thinking about it incorrectly?

Comment: I think I understand. extend the locations_list with notifyWhenChangesStop, then subscribe to locations_list and only load the selected data inside the subscription. Thanks Max.

Comment: @max is it possible to subscribe to a observable Array ? any documentation on this anywhere ? Thanks . when we push something something new subscribe will fire but when i change something inside observableArray i.e observable value its not getting fired . ? any idea .

Comment: @supercool It's expected behavior. You can use `observable` instead of `observableArray` or you can use `valueHasMutated` or `replace` methods.